Find up/downregulated gene lists across scRNA-seq samples
I have two separate scRNA-seq datasets that are different batches. I want to get genelists of up/downregulation of one cluster in one dataset compared to another cluster in the other dataset.
I already did integration using scanorama on Scanpy and the anchor method on Seurat (I can use either tool) but the Satija Lab clearly says on github that you can't do differential expression analysis on batch-corrected data.
Can I just append anndata/seurat objects from different batches and do DE without batch correction? Or is there something I'm missing?
